# Format for ordinal dates (day of month with suffixes -st, -nd, -rd, -th)

Tags: r, date

Am I missing something? I can't figure out how to convert the following to `Date`s, where day of the month (`%d`) has the ordinal suffixes `-st`, `-nd`, `-rd`, `-th`:

```
ord_dates <- c("September 1st, 2016", "September 2nd, 2016",
               "September 3rd, 2016", "September 4th, 2016")
```

`?strptime` doesn't appear to list a shorthand for the ordinal suffix, and it isn't handled automagically:

```
as.Date(ord_dates, format = c("%B %d, %Y"))
#[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Is there a token for handling ignored characters in the `format` argument? A token I'm missing?

Best I can come up with is (there may a shorter regex, but same idea):

```
as.Date(gsub("([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)", "\\1", ord_dates), format = "%B %d, %Y")
# [1] "2016-09-01" "2016-09-02" "2016-09-03" "2016-09-04"
```

Seems like this sort of data should be relatively common; am I missing something?

Comment: Here's a shorter regex: `as.Date(sub("([0-9]+).*,", "\\1", ord_dates), format = c("%B %d %Y"))`

Comment: Hm, I'm no regex expert but I guess it should be, when strings are long and the first match is early in the string (so it won't have to traverse the rest).

Comment: About the simplest you can do in base: `as.Date(sub('\\D+,', '', ord_dates), '%B %e %Y')`. Everything in the format string that's not a token is taken as a literal (except `%%`, which is taken as a literal `%`), so there's very frustratingly no wildcards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enjoy the power of `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)    
mdy(ord_dates)

[1] "2016-09-01" "2016-09-02" "2016-09-03" "2016-09-04"
```

Internally, `lubridate` doesn't have any special conversion specifications which enable this. Rather, `lubridate` first uses (by smart guessing) the format `"%B %dst, %Y"`. This gets the first element of `ord_dates`.

It then checks for `NA`s and repeats its smart guessing on the remaining elements, settling on `"%B %dnd, %Y"` to get the second element. It continues in this way until there are no `NA`s left (which happens in this case after 4 iterations), or until its smart guessing fails to turn up a likely format candidate.

You can imagine this makes `lubridate` slower, and it does -- about half the speed of just using the smart regex suggested by @alistaire above:

```
set.seed(109123)
ord_dates <- sample(
  c("September 1st, 2016", "September 2nd, 2016",
    "September 3rd, 2016", "September 4th, 2016"),
  1e6, TRUE
  )

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(times = 10L,
               lubridate = mdy(ord_dates),
               base = as.Date(sub("\\D+,", "", ord_dates),
                              format = "%B %e %Y"))
# Unit: seconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  lubridate 2.167957 2.219463 2.290950 2.252565 2.301725 2.587724    10   b
#       base 1.183970 1.224824 1.218642 1.227034 1.228324 1.229095    10  a
```

The obvious advantage in `lubridate`'s favor being its conciseness and flexibility.